How to remove duplicates and inc table records using postgres sql regex
I have created scenario in fiddle where I have to remove  duplicate records and keep only 1 record example : for spotted table mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job there are 2 records so need to remove duplicate and keep only 1.
select field1
  ,unnest(
      regexp_matches(
         replace(
            replace(
               concat('''' 
                      ||replace(
                           replace(
                              ltrim(rtrim(field2))
                             ,'"'
                             ,''
                           )
                          ,''''
                          ,''
                        )
                      ||''''
               )
              ,'"'
              ,''
            )
           ,E'\n'
           ,'')
        --,'(?:UPDATE|INTO|FROM|JOIN|USING|TABLE)(?:\s+ONLY)*\s+([[:alpha:]._]+[[:word:]]*|"[^"]+")'
        ,'(?:FROM)(?:\s+ONLY)*\s+([[:alpha:]._]+[[:word:]]*|"[^"]+")','gi'
      )
   ) AS spotted_table
  ,field2
from table1;




field1
spotted_table
field2




a
mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job
select service_management.analyze_table(kanban_job,mfg_lz_inc);DELETE FROM mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job  WHERE dw_upd_dtsz < To_Date(Cast(extract (year from (Current_Timestamp))-7 AS CHAR(4))||/02/01,yyyy/mm/dd);DELETE FROM mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job AWHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job B WHERE A.recid = B.recid and A.KANBAN=B.KANBAN);INSERT into mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job(ACTUALENDDATETIME,ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,DEFAULTDIMENSION,DUEDATETIME,DUEDATETIMETZID,EXECUTABLE,EXPECTEDDATETIME,EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INVENTDIMID,INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INVENTLOCATIONID,INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INVENTTRANSID,ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTDIMID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,KANBAN,LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,PLANACTIVITYNAME,QUANTITYORDERED,QUANTITYRECEIVED,QUANTITYSCRAPPED,SEQUENCE,SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,STATUS,TYPEE,WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,WMSLOCATIONID,WORKCELL,LOADPERCENT,PARTITIONN,RECID,RECVERSION,AXLWIPENDDATETIME,AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,AXLFIS,MANUALCLEAR,MODIFIEDBY,TERMINAL,MODIFIEDDATETIME,MODIFIEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME,CREATEDBY,KFK_INS_DTSZ,SRC_SYS_NM,DW_ROW_HASH_VAL,DW_SRC_SITE_ID,DW_INS_DTSZ,DW_UPD_DTSZ,DW_LD_GRP_VAL,DW_ETL_SESS_NM)   select INC_L.ACTUALENDDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.DEFAULTDIMENSION,INC_L.DUEDATETIME,INC_L.DUEDATETIMETZID,INC_L.EXECUTABLE,INC_L.EXPECTEDDATETIME,INC_L.EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTDIMID,INC_L.INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTLOCATIONID,INC_L.INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTTRANSID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTDIMID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,INC_L.KANBAN,INC_L.LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,INC_L.PLANACTIVITYNAME,INC_L.QUANTITYORDERED,INC_L.QUANTITYRECEIVED,INC_L.QUANTITYSCRAPPED,INC_L.SEQUENCE,INC_L.SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,INC_L.STATUS,INC_L.TYPEE,INC_L.WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INC_L.WMSLOCATIONID,INC_L.WORKCELL,INC_L.LOADPERCENT,INC_L.PARTITIONN,INC_L.RECID,INC_L.RECVERSION,INC_L.AXLWIPENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLFIS,INC_L.MANUALCLEAR,INC_L.MODIFIEDBY,INC_L.TERMINAL,INC_L.MODIFIEDDATETIME,INC_L.MODIFIEDBY,INC_L.CREATEDDATETIME,INC_L.CREATEDBY,INC_L.KFK_INS_DTSZ,COALESCE(INC_L.src_sys_nm, ) AS src_sys_nm,md5(coalesce(cast(INC_L.recid as varchar(100))||cast(INC_L.KANBAN as varchar(100))||cast(INC_L.src_sys_nm as varchar(100)),1))  as dw_row_hash_val,1040 as dw_src_site_id,current_timestamp as dw_ins_dtsz,current_timestamp as dw_upd_dtsz,cast((to_char(current_timestamp, YYYYMMDDHH24MI)||.00) as numeric) as dw_ld_grp_val,ICM_INVSSF_DDLDSC_KFK_GPSS_ICC_AXBI_KANBAN_JOB as dw_etl_sess_nm  from (select ACTUALENDDATETIME,ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,DEFAULTDIMENSION,DUEDATETIME,DUEDATETIMETZID,EXECUTABLE,EXPECTEDDATETIME,EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INVENTDIMID,INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INVENTLOCATIONID,INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INVENTTRANSID,ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTDIMID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,KANBAN,LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,PLANACTIVITYNAME,QUANTITYORDERED,QUANTITYRECEIVED,QUANTITYSCRAPPED,SEQUENCE,SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,STATUS,TYPEE,WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,WMSLOCATIONID,WORKCELL,LOADPERCENT,PARTITIONN,RECID,RECVERSION,AXLWIPENDDATETIME,AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,AXLFIS,MANUALCLEAR,MODIFIEDBY,TERMINAL,MODIFIEDDATETIME,MODIFIEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME,CREATEDBY,KFK_INS_DTSZ,SRC_SYS_NM,row_number ()over (partition by recid,kanban,src_sys_nm order by kfk_ins_dtsz desc) as first_value       from mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job) INC_Lwhere first_value=1;select service_management.analyze_table(icc_axbi_kanban_job,mfg_lz);


a
mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job
select service_management.analyze_table(kanban_job,mfg_lz_inc);DELETE FROM mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job  WHERE dw_upd_dtsz < To_Date(Cast(extract (year from (Current_Timestamp))-7 AS CHAR(4))||/02/01,yyyy/mm/dd);DELETE FROM mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job AWHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job B WHERE A.recid = B.recid and A.KANBAN=B.KANBAN);INSERT into mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job(ACTUALENDDATETIME,ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,DEFAULTDIMENSION,DUEDATETIME,DUEDATETIMETZID,EXECUTABLE,EXPECTEDDATETIME,EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INVENTDIMID,INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INVENTLOCATIONID,INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INVENTTRANSID,ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTDIMID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,KANBAN,LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,PLANACTIVITYNAME,QUANTITYORDERED,QUANTITYRECEIVED,QUANTITYSCRAPPED,SEQUENCE,SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,STATUS,TYPEE,WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,WMSLOCATIONID,WORKCELL,LOADPERCENT,PARTITIONN,RECID,RECVERSION,AXLWIPENDDATETIME,AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,AXLFIS,MANUALCLEAR,MODIFIEDBY,TERMINAL,MODIFIEDDATETIME,MODIFIEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME,CREATEDBY,KFK_INS_DTSZ,SRC_SYS_NM,DW_ROW_HASH_VAL,DW_SRC_SITE_ID,DW_INS_DTSZ,DW_UPD_DTSZ,DW_LD_GRP_VAL,DW_ETL_SESS_NM)   select INC_L.ACTUALENDDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.DEFAULTDIMENSION,INC_L.DUEDATETIME,INC_L.DUEDATETIMETZID,INC_L.EXECUTABLE,INC_L.EXPECTEDDATETIME,INC_L.EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTDIMID,INC_L.INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTLOCATIONID,INC_L.INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTTRANSID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTDIMID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,INC_L.KANBAN,INC_L.LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,INC_L.PLANACTIVITYNAME,INC_L.QUANTITYORDERED,INC_L.QUANTITYRECEIVED,INC_L.QUANTITYSCRAPPED,INC_L.SEQUENCE,INC_L.SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,INC_L.STATUS,INC_L.TYPEE,INC_L.WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INC_L.WMSLOCATIONID,INC_L.WORKCELL,INC_L.LOADPERCENT,INC_L.PARTITIONN,INC_L.RECID,INC_L.RECVERSION,INC_L.AXLWIPENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLFIS,INC_L.MANUALCLEAR,INC_L.MODIFIEDBY,INC_L.TERMINAL,INC_L.MODIFIEDDATETIME,INC_L.MODIFIEDBY,INC_L.CREATEDDATETIME,INC_L.CREATEDBY,INC_L.KFK_INS_DTSZ,COALESCE(INC_L.src_sys_nm, ) AS src_sys_nm,md5(coalesce(cast(INC_L.recid as varchar(100))||cast(INC_L.KANBAN as varchar(100))||cast(INC_L.src_sys_nm as varchar(100)),1))  as dw_row_hash_val,1040 as dw_src_site_id,current_timestamp as dw_ins_dtsz,current_timestamp as dw_upd_dtsz,cast((to_char(current_timestamp, YYYYMMDDHH24MI)||.00) as numeric) as dw_ld_grp_val,ICM_INVSSF_DDLDSC_KFK_GPSS_ICC_AXBI_KANBAN_JOB as dw_etl_sess_nm  from (select ACTUALENDDATETIME,ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,DEFAULTDIMENSION,DUEDATETIME,DUEDATETIMETZID,EXECUTABLE,EXPECTEDDATETIME,EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INVENTDIMID,INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INVENTLOCATIONID,INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INVENTTRANSID,ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTDIMID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,KANBAN,LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,PLANACTIVITYNAME,QUANTITYORDERED,QUANTITYRECEIVED,QUANTITYSCRAPPED,SEQUENCE,SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,STATUS,TYPEE,WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,WMSLOCATIONID,WORKCELL,LOADPERCENT,PARTITIONN,RECID,RECVERSION,AXLWIPENDDATETIME,AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,AXLFIS,MANUALCLEAR,MODIFIEDBY,TERMINAL,MODIFIEDDATETIME,MODIFIEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME,CREATEDBY,KFK_INS_DTSZ,SRC_SYS_NM,row_number ()over (partition by recid,kanban,src_sys_nm order by kfk_ins_dtsz desc) as first_value       from mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job) INC_Lwhere first_value=1;select service_management.analyze_table(icc_axbi_kanban_job,mfg_lz);


a
mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job
select service_management.analyze_table(kanban_job,mfg_lz_inc);DELETE FROM mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job  WHERE dw_upd_dtsz < To_Date(Cast(extract (year from (Current_Timestamp))-7 AS CHAR(4))||/02/01,yyyy/mm/dd);DELETE FROM mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job AWHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job B WHERE A.recid = B.recid and A.KANBAN=B.KANBAN);INSERT into mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job(ACTUALENDDATETIME,ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,DEFAULTDIMENSION,DUEDATETIME,DUEDATETIMETZID,EXECUTABLE,EXPECTEDDATETIME,EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INVENTDIMID,INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INVENTLOCATIONID,INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INVENTTRANSID,ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTDIMID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,KANBAN,LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,PLANACTIVITYNAME,QUANTITYORDERED,QUANTITYRECEIVED,QUANTITYSCRAPPED,SEQUENCE,SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,STATUS,TYPEE,WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,WMSLOCATIONID,WORKCELL,LOADPERCENT,PARTITIONN,RECID,RECVERSION,AXLWIPENDDATETIME,AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,AXLFIS,MANUALCLEAR,MODIFIEDBY,TERMINAL,MODIFIEDDATETIME,MODIFIEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME,CREATEDBY,KFK_INS_DTSZ,SRC_SYS_NM,DW_ROW_HASH_VAL,DW_SRC_SITE_ID,DW_INS_DTSZ,DW_UPD_DTSZ,DW_LD_GRP_VAL,DW_ETL_SESS_NM)  select INC_L.ACTUALENDDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.DEFAULTDIMENSION,INC_L.DUEDATETIME,INC_L.DUEDATETIMETZID,INC_L.EXECUTABLE,INC_L.EXPECTEDDATETIME,INC_L.EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTDIMID,INC_L.INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTLOCATIONID,INC_L.INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTTRANSID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTDIMID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,INC_L.KANBAN,INC_L.LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,INC_L.PLANACTIVITYNAME,INC_L.QUANTITYORDERED,INC_L.QUANTITYRECEIVED,INC_L.QUANTITYSCRAPPED,INC_L.SEQUENCE,INC_L.SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,INC_L.STATUS,INC_L.TYPEE,INC_L.WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INC_L.WMSLOCATIONID,INC_L.WORKCELL,INC_L.LOADPERCENT,INC_L.PARTITIONN,INC_L.RECID,INC_L.RECVERSION,INC_L.AXLWIPENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLFIS,INC_L.MANUALCLEAR,INC_L.MODIFIEDBY,INC_L.TERMINAL,INC_L.MODIFIEDDATETIME,INC_L.MODIFIEDBY,INC_L.CREATEDDATETIME,INC_L.CREATEDBY,INC_L.KFK_INS_DTSZ,COALESCE(INC_L.src_sys_nm, ) AS src_sys_nm,md5(coalesce(cast(INC_L.recid as varchar(100))||cast(INC_L.KANBAN as varchar(100))||cast(INC_L.src_sys_nm as varchar(100)),1))  as dw_row_hash_val,1040 as dw_src_site_id,current_timestamp as dw_ins_dtsz,current_timestamp as dw_upd_dtsz,cast((to_char(current_timestamp, YYYYMMDDHH24MI)||.00) as numeric) as dw_ld_grp_val,ICM_INVSSF_DDLDSC_KFK_GPSS_ICC_AXBI_KANBAN_JOB as dw_etl_sess_nm  from (select ACTUALENDDATETIME,ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,DEFAULTDIMENSION,DUEDATETIME,DUEDATETIMETZID,EXECUTABLE,EXPECTEDDATETIME,EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INVENTDIMID,INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INVENTLOCATIONID,INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INVENTTRANSID,ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTDIMID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,KANBAN,LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,PLANACTIVITYNAME,QUANTITYORDERED,QUANTITYRECEIVED,QUANTITYSCRAPPED,SEQUENCE,SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,STATUS,TYPEE,WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,WMSLOCATIONID,WORKCELL,LOADPERCENT,PARTITIONN,RECID,RECVERSION,AXLWIPENDDATETIME,AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,AXLFIS,MANUALCLEAR,MODIFIEDBY,TERMINAL,MODIFIEDDATETIME,MODIFIEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME,CREATEDBY,KFK_INS_DTSZ,SRC_SYS_NM,row_number ()over (partition by recid,kanban,src_sys_nm order by kfk_ins_dtsz desc) as first_value       from mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job) INC_Lwhere first_value=1;select service_management.analyze_table(icc_axbi_kanban_job,mfg_lz);


a
mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job
select service_management.analyze_table(kanban_job,mfg_lz_inc);DELETE FROM mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job  WHERE dw_upd_dtsz < To_Date(Cast(extract (year from (Current_Timestamp))-7 AS CHAR(4))||/02/01,yyyy/mm/dd);DELETE FROM mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job AWHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job B WHERE A.recid = B.recid and A.KANBAN=B.KANBAN);INSERT into mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job(ACTUALENDDATETIME,ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,DEFAULTDIMENSION,DUEDATETIME,DUEDATETIMETZID,EXECUTABLE,EXPECTEDDATETIME,EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INVENTDIMID,INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INVENTLOCATIONID,INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INVENTTRANSID,ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTDIMID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,KANBAN,LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,PLANACTIVITYNAME,QUANTITYORDERED,QUANTITYRECEIVED,QUANTITYSCRAPPED,SEQUENCE,SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,STATUS,TYPEE,WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,WMSLOCATIONID,WORKCELL,LOADPERCENT,PARTITIONN,RECID,RECVERSION,AXLWIPENDDATETIME,AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,AXLFIS,MANUALCLEAR,MODIFIEDBY,TERMINAL,MODIFIEDDATETIME,MODIFIEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME,CREATEDBY,KFK_INS_DTSZ,SRC_SYS_NM,DW_ROW_HASH_VAL,DW_SRC_SITE_ID,DW_INS_DTSZ,DW_UPD_DTSZ,DW_LD_GRP_VAL,DW_ETL_SESS_NM)  select INC_L.ACTUALENDDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.DEFAULTDIMENSION,INC_L.DUEDATETIME,INC_L.DUEDATETIMETZID,INC_L.EXECUTABLE,INC_L.EXPECTEDDATETIME,INC_L.EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTDIMID,INC_L.INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTLOCATIONID,INC_L.INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTTRANSID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTDIMID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,INC_L.KANBAN,INC_L.LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,INC_L.PLANACTIVITYNAME,INC_L.QUANTITYORDERED,INC_L.QUANTITYRECEIVED,INC_L.QUANTITYSCRAPPED,INC_L.SEQUENCE,INC_L.SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,INC_L.STATUS,INC_L.TYPEE,INC_L.WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INC_L.WMSLOCATIONID,INC_L.WORKCELL,INC_L.LOADPERCENT,INC_L.PARTITIONN,INC_L.RECID,INC_L.RECVERSION,INC_L.AXLWIPENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLFIS,INC_L.MANUALCLEAR,INC_L.MODIFIEDBY,INC_L.TERMINAL,INC_L.MODIFIEDDATETIME,INC_L.MODIFIEDBY,INC_L.CREATEDDATETIME,INC_L.CREATEDBY,INC_L.KFK_INS_DTSZ,COALESCE(INC_L.src_sys_nm, ) AS src_sys_nm,md5(coalesce(cast(INC_L.recid as varchar(100))||cast(INC_L.KANBAN as varchar(100))||cast(INC_L.src_sys_nm as varchar(100)),1))  as dw_row_hash_val,1040 as dw_src_site_id,current_timestamp as dw_ins_dtsz,current_timestamp as dw_upd_dtsz,cast((to_char(current_timestamp, YYYYMMDDHH24MI)||.00) as numeric) as dw_ld_grp_val,ICM_INVSSF_DDLDSC_KFK_GPSS_ICC_AXBI_KANBAN_JOB as dw_etl_sess_nm  from (select ACTUALENDDATETIME,ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,DEFAULTDIMENSION,DUEDATETIME,DUEDATETIMETZID,EXECUTABLE,EXPECTEDDATETIME,EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INVENTDIMID,INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INVENTLOCATIONID,INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INVENTTRANSID,ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTDIMID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,KANBAN,LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,PLANACTIVITYNAME,QUANTITYORDERED,QUANTITYRECEIVED,QUANTITYSCRAPPED,SEQUENCE,SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,STATUS,TYPEE,WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,WMSLOCATIONID,WORKCELL,LOADPERCENT,PARTITIONN,RECID,RECVERSION,AXLWIPENDDATETIME,AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,AXLFIS,MANUALCLEAR,MODIFIEDBY,TERMINAL,MODIFIEDDATETIME,MODIFIEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME,CREATEDBY,KFK_INS_DTSZ,SRC_SYS_NM,row_number ()over (partition by recid,kanban,src_sys_nm order by kfk_ins_dtsz desc) as first_value       from mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job) INC_Lwhere first_value=1;select service_management.analyze_table(icc_axbi_kanban_job,mfg_lz);



Also I don't need records where spotted table is having inc schema suffix like mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job.
So ideally I am expecting only 1 row in output with spotted table mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job.
However currently I am getting 4 rows. What should I write in regex to achieve that output?


There's btrim() if you want to use both rtrim() and ltrim().
If you need multiple replace(), you can use a single translate().
You called concat() with a single argument, that you constructed by concatenating with ||. You only need one of these: separate arguments passed to concat() with commas, or remove concat() entirely and concatenate with only || instead.
[:word:] and [:alpha:] character classes are available in PostgreSQL 14 onwards. Assuming you're on 9.5 (highest version tag you used), you can swap those out for a \w, downgrading your regex a bit (it now allows identifiers to start with a digit, which is not allowed).
You're currently catching only the schema in qualified names. You can expand the expression to tolerate dots in unquoted identifiers, or just an optional one in the middle of two quoted identifiers.
You can use distinct on(spotted_table)...order by spotted_table to get just one row for each distinct table. Or, if you plan to aggregate, you can add it in the aggregate function: string_agg(distinct spotted_table,',').

Demo at db<>fiddle:
with cte as (
    select field1,field2
          ,translate(''''||
              translate( btrim(field2)
                        , '"''', '' )
              ||''''
             , E'\n"', '' ) as edited_field2 
  from table1)
,cte2 as (
    select *,t.spotted_table as spotted_target,s.spotted_table as spotted_source
    from cte
    left join regexp_matches(
         edited_field2
        ,'(?:UPDATE|INTO)(?:\s+ONLY)?\s+([[:alpha:]_]+[\.\w]*|"[^"]+"(?:\."[^"]+")?)'
        ,'gi'
      ) with ordinality as target_matches(hits,n1) on true
  left join unnest(target_matches.hits) with ordinality as t(spotted_table,n2) on true
  left join   regexp_matches(
         edited_field2
        ,'(?:FROM|JOIN|USING|TABLE)(?:\s+ONLY)?\s+([[:alpha:]_]+[\.\w]*|"[^"]+"(?:\."[^"]+")?)'
        ,'gi'
      ) with ordinality as source_matches(hits,n1) on true
  left join unnest(source_matches.hits) with ordinality as s(spotted_table,n2) on true)
select field1
      ,string_agg(distinct spotted_target,',') as spotted_targets
      ,string_agg(distinct spotted_source,',') as spotted_sources
      ,edited_field2
from cte2
where coalesce(split_part(spotted_target,'.',1) !~* '_inc"?$',true)
  and coalesce(split_part(spotted_source,'.',1) !~* '_inc"?$',true)
group by field1,edited_field2;




field1
spotted_targets
spotted_sources
edited_field2




a
mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job
mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job
'select service_management.analyze_table(kanban_job,mfg_lz_inc);DELETE FROM mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job  WHERE dw_upd_dtsz < To_Date(Cast(extract (year from (Current_Timestamp))-7 AS CHAR(4))||/02/01,yyyy/mm/dd);DELETE FROM mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job AWHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job B WHERE A.recid = B.recid and A.KANBAN=B.KANBAN);INSERT into mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job(ACTUALENDDATETIME,ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,DEFAULTDIMENSION,DUEDATETIME,DUEDATETIMETZID,EXECUTABLE,EXPECTEDDATETIME,EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INVENTDIMID,INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INVENTLOCATIONID,INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INVENTTRANSID,ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTDIMID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,KANBAN,LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,PLANACTIVITYNAME,QUANTITYORDERED,QUANTITYRECEIVED,QUANTITYSCRAPPED,SEQUENCE,SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,STATUS,TYPEE,WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,WMSLOCATIONID,WORKCELL,LOADPERCENT,PARTITIONN,RECID,RECVERSION,AXLWIPENDDATETIME,AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,AXLFIS,MANUALCLEAR,MODIFIEDBY,TERMINAL,MODIFIEDDATETIME,MODIFIEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME,CREATEDBY,KFK_INS_DTSZ,SRC_SYS_NM,DW_ROW_HASH_VAL,DW_SRC_SITE_ID,DW_INS_DTSZ,DW_UPD_DTSZ,DW_LD_GRP_VAL,DW_ETL_SESS_NM) select INC_L.ACTUALENDDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.DEFAULTDIMENSION,INC_L.DUEDATETIME,INC_L.DUEDATETIMETZID,INC_L.EXECUTABLE,INC_L.EXPECTEDDATETIME,INC_L.EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTDIMID,INC_L.INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTLOCATIONID,INC_L.INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INC_L.INVENTTRANSID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTDIMID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INC_L.ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,INC_L.KANBAN,INC_L.LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,INC_L.LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,INC_L.PLANACTIVITYNAME,INC_L.QUANTITYORDERED,INC_L.QUANTITYRECEIVED,INC_L.QUANTITYSCRAPPED,INC_L.SEQUENCE,INC_L.SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,INC_L.STATUS,INC_L.TYPEE,INC_L.WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INC_L.WMSLOCATIONID,INC_L.WORKCELL,INC_L.LOADPERCENT,INC_L.PARTITIONN,INC_L.RECID,INC_L.RECVERSION,INC_L.AXLWIPENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,INC_L.AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,INC_L.AXLFIS,INC_L.MANUALCLEAR,INC_L.MODIFIEDBY,INC_L.TERMINAL,INC_L.MODIFIEDDATETIME,INC_L.MODIFIEDBY,INC_L.CREATEDDATETIME,INC_L.CREATEDBY,INC_L.KFK_INS_DTSZ,COALESCE(INC_L.src_sys_nm, ) AS src_sys_nm,md5(coalesce(cast(INC_L.recid as varchar(100))||cast(INC_L.KANBAN as varchar(100))||cast(INC_L.src_sys_nm as varchar(100)),1))  as dw_row_hash_val,1040 as dw_src_site_id,current_timestamp as dw_ins_dtsz,current_timestamp as dw_upd_dtsz,cast((to_char(current_timestamp, YYYYMMDDHH24MI)||.00) as numeric) as dw_ld_grp_val,ICM_INVSSF_DDLDSC_KFK_GPSS_ICC_AXBI_KANBAN_JOB as dw_etl_sess_nm  from (select ACTUALENDDATETIME,ACTUALENDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIME,ACTUALPREPAREDDATETIMETZID,ACTUALSTARTDATETIME,ACTUALSTARTDATETIMETZID,DEFAULTDIMENSION,DUEDATETIME,DUEDATETIMETZID,EXECUTABLE,EXPECTEDDATETIME,EXPECTEDDATETIMETZID,INVENTDIMDATAAREAID,INVENTDIMID,INVENTLOCATIONDATAAREAID,INVENTLOCATIONID,INVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,INVENTTRANSID,ISSUEINVENTDIMDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTDIMID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSDATAAREAID,ISSUEINVENTTRANSID,KANBAN,LEANPRODUCTIONFLOWACTIVITY,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPCOLOR,LEANSCHEDULEGROUPNAME,LEANSCHEDULEITEMRATIO,PLANACTIVITYNAME,QUANTITYORDERED,QUANTITYRECEIVED,QUANTITYSCRAPPED,SEQUENCE,SOURCEDOCUMENTHEADER,STATUS,TYPEE,WMSLOCATIONDATAAREAID,WMSLOCATIONID,WORKCELL,LOADPERCENT,PARTITIONN,RECID,RECVERSION,AXLWIPENDDATETIME,AXLWIPENDDATETIMETZID,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLESTIMATEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLRESOURCECONSTRAINEDJOBTIMEMINUTES,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATE,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDSTARTDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYPLANNEDENDDATETIMETZID,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIME,AXLKANBANACTIVITYSCHEDULINGENDDATETIMETZID,AXLFIS,MANUALCLEAR,MODIFIEDBY,TERMINAL,MODIFIEDDATETIME,MODIFIEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME,CREATEDBY,KFK_INS_DTSZ,SRC_SYS_NM,row_number ()over (partition by recid,kanban,src_sys_nm order by kfk_ins_dtsz desc) as first_value       from mfg_lz_inc.icc_axbi_kanban_job) INC_Lwhere first_value=1;select service_management.analyze_table(icc_axbi_kanban_job,mfg_lz);'




Consider the pre-built SQL parser tools recommended previously instead of the regular expressions.
All versions you tagged are no longer supported. Consider an update.


@zegarek-How to fit this query if I need to aggregate the records with multiple tables (',') like you helped previously.https://dbfiddle.uk/BI3-zRys.Also as a short term solution I am working on regex as we have commitment and limited time but for long term I am working on sql parser as well using python as advised.

@Ram You can wrap that in another CTE, and add field1 to the order by in order to keep unique spotted tables, but separately for each query. demo

@Ram Here's the older demo with updated regex, schema-qualification support and filtering out schemas with _inc suffix (schema3_inc in example t gets filtered out from the sources): demo

Thank you so much @Zegarek....In old demo, I have checked duplicates are still coming added row with field as u . demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/5V1wQXMk

@Ram Here's "the old one" with both queries, merged: demo

Thank you @Zegarek for sharing your best knowledge.I will raise questions regarding sql parser soon for long term solutions...once I will complete this short term solution

@Ram
You can try to remove the duplicates by identifying which duplicates you have.
For that you may do the removal in two phases:
Phase 1: Identification of duplicates:
a) GROUP BY clause, to identify only the duplicates;
b) and make sure your table's primary key is correctly set;
c) ctid hidden column on PostgreSQL do delete only the one you want;
For example:
   SELECT primary_key_you_have, count(*) 
     FROM mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job 
    GROUP BY mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job.primary_key_you_have
   HAVING count(*) > 1

(presumabily the primary_key_you_have is your primary key, so please replace with the one your table have).
Phase 2: Removal of duplicates.
In that scenario you will have then to DELETE manually based on your ctid.
Because of that make sure you take notes beforehand with the output given from
the Phase 1.
For each primary key(s) you use:
  SELECT ctid, * FROM primary_key_you_have WHERE = 'value_obatained_from_phase_1' ;
   

  DELETE FROM mfg_lz.icc_axbi_kanban_job WHERE CTID = '(x,y);

Iteract for who many CTID you have in the duplicated output until there is only one, and make sure you don't deleat the last one. Use the values double-check if they are indeed duplicated.
IMPORTANT: if you don't have primary keys (and therefore your model doesn't planned it - so it's more like a database design problem rather than a database failure and you may have to try a different approach)
An alternative approach would be to add all columns in the group by clause.

It's not about duplicates in the tables spotted in the query bodies in field2. It's about duplicates of those spotted tables on the output.

Got it, I have replied the first version of the question before you have modified. I will leave it here for historical reaons only if that helps other.
